# Significado de los "costumbres"

Tags: significado, literatura

Estaba leyendo el libro *El extranjero* de Albert Camus y encontré esta frase:

> Primero había pensado en llevarla a un hotel y llamar a los "costumbres" para provocar un escándalo y hacerla fichar como prostituta.

Mi pregunta es: ¿Qué significa "los costumbres" en este caso?

Comment: La frase y, en particular, la elección de la palabra que genera tu duda, en realidad no son de Albert Camus, sino del traductor. ¿Podrías indicar quién es? Creo que es el mínimo reconocimiento que se merecen las personas que hacen el trabajo de traductores.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Es una traducción del francés **mœurs**, que literalmente significa "modales".

Se refiere a los policías de la [Brigade des mœurs](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brigade_des_m%C5%93urs), dedicados a asuntos de moralidad pública. Por el entrecomillado yo supongo que en la época de la historia les decían simplemente "*mœurs*".

Al parecer en algunos países existe o ha existido un equivalente llamado la *policía de costumbres*.

Comment: Qué interesante, tipo la Guardia Revolucionaria de Irán en la actualidad

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' I am sure you must have an equivalent branch of the police which deals with prostitution, pornography, illicit substances and so on.

Comment: @mdewey yes, of course, even though the police Camus and Rodrigo (what a good combination of people :D) are referring to is the [_morality squad_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vice#Vice_squad) which fortunately is long gone in our areas.

Answer (score 4):

Por complementar la [respuesta de Rodrigo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/34672/12637), se pueden encontrar muchas referencias en textos de España a la "policía de las costumbres". Por ejemplo, tienes el siguiente fragmento:

> *[...] saber que en los gobiernos de provincia, como había secciones de Fomento y Hacienda, existía también de higiene (así llamadas al parecer, más que por decencia por burla) que tenían á su cargo la policía de las costumbres, y eran, y no podían menos de ser, un elemento poderoso para pervertirlas; saber que esa policía podía poner su mano infame sobre una mujer honesta, presentarla como sospechosa, hacerla sufrir la última ignominia repugnante hasta para las prostitutas, y que si la mujer no quería salir viva del lugar donde fué deshonrada y se precipitaba por la ventana quedando muerta, sus asesinos no eran responsables, porque no habían hecho más que cumplir con los reglamentos [...].*
>
> Concepción Arenal, "El pauperismo", p 1885 (España).

Como puedes ver, el tema de este texto tiene mucho que ver con el texto de Albert Camus de hacer pasar a una mujer respetable como prostituta simplemente denunciándola ante la policía de las costumbres, o "los costumbres", como expresa la traducción del texto de Camus. Entiendo que se usó "los costumbres" por ser el término empleado comúnmente en España para referirse a esta policía.

Las menciones a la policía de las costumbres se documentan desde 1787 en textos de la hemeroteca de la Biblioteca Nacional de España, aunque a partir de 1877 empiezan a ser más frecuentes, como el siguiente:

> *»A los pocos meses salió* La Voz del desierto, *enérgica y conmovedora protesta de la mujer oprimida que se rebela por fin contra la iniquidad, la barbarie, la ignominia de las
>   leyes y ordenanzas relativas á la policía de las costumbres, cuyas leyes pesan sobre su sexo por el único derecho de ser el hombre el más fuerte, para general maldicion de la familia humana.*
>
> La Voz de la caridad. 15/6/1877, [página 6](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/issue.vm?id=0069887226&page=6&search=%22polic%C3%ADa%20de%20las%20costumbres%22&lang=es).